# Arduino Wifi ESP8266

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

First, do I need 2 Arduino Unos with ESP8266 module installed to communicate with each other?

I want to transmit ultrasonic value from 1 Arduino Uno to another. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: you don't need any UNOs, but if you wanted to talk uno-to-uno, how can you not need 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of an Arduino to comunicate 2 ESP8266 modules. Maybe you can read that ultrasonic value with the ESP and send it to another or to the internet. Check this [tutorial](http://www.whatimade.today/esp8266-easiest-way-to-program-so-far/) maybe will be useful.